# Google Guava - Does using Ordering() make sorting faster than using Comparator?

Tags: java, guava

Apart from enriching Comparators, does Ordering() provide performance improvement over using basic Comparators?

What are the scenarios where [Ordering()](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Ordering.html#Ordering()) is best suited to the use-case, instead of Comparators?

Comment: An Ordering **is a** Comparator.

Comment: I wanted to know performance diff between Collections.sort(list, Comparator) vs Collections.sort(list, Ordering)

Comment: `Ordering` offers convenience methods for creating and using comparators. It's not supposed to offer performance enhancements over any particular `Comparator` implementation, though Guava generally tries to optimize performance when possible (see Javadoc to [`Ordering.immutableSortedCopy()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Ordering.html#immutableSortedCopy(java.lang.Iterable)) for an example).

Comment: @a3.14_Infinity No difference.  Seriously.  The point of `Ordering` is the extra methods it provides, not any speed difference.

Comment: Thanks. If there was a speed difference, I had a choice of using Ordering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a single `Collections.sort()` method, that takes a Comparator as argument. And an Ordering **is a** Comparator. So, the exact same sorting algorithm is used whether you call `Collections.sort()` with a Comparator or with an Ordering.

The only difference might be in the code of the comparator/ordering. An Ordering is typically created **from** a Comparator, and only **delegates** to it. Here's the code of ComparatorOrdering's compare method:

```
public int compare(T a, T b) {
    return comparator.compare(a, b);
}
```

So, if you sort using a comparator, or if you sort using an Ordering that wraps this same comparator, the performance will be almost identical. There could be a slightly better performance with the "raw" comparator, since it doesn't have the cost of delegating to another object that the Ordering has. But this cost is probably 0, because the JIT will most probably inline the delegation.

Anyway, nearly all the static factory methods and the instance methods of Ordering now exist in plain Java 8. So, if a functionality of Ordering exists that you can't find in the JDK, then use an Ordering. Otherwise, just use a Comparator. The performance difference, if any, is negligible.

Comment: I assume from your answer that, there is no speed difference.

Answer (score 0):

if you see the definition of `ordering` you Found something like

```
@GwtCompatible
public abstract class Ordering<T>
extends Object
implements Comparator<T>
```

It means it internally one child of `Comparator`. I am not talking about the `efficiency` . but as per my assumption it will never be faster because `Comaparator` is more native and nearer to `Java` than any other Child of `Comparator` (like **Ordering**) `Interface` . So Comparator must be more efficient than any other.
[Ordering Class Google Docs](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Ordering.html)

Comment: `Comparator` on its own doesn't have an implementation. It doesn't make sense to discuss the efficiency of `Comparator` as an interface.